# Compare phone numbers to find duplicates across different sheet columns

Tags: google-sheets

I want to compare phone numbers between different sheet columns.

How do I use conditional formatting to find duplicates values?

Comment: in my sheet there is call A sheet "D3:D" & B sheet "D3:D". Should make color indication between them.

Comment: please edit your question instead of commenting., there is a `edit` link below of it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try clearing formatting from and selecting A!D:D and Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... **Custom formula is** and:

```
=countif(indirect("B!D1:D"),D1)
```

Then select formatting of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Repeat to suit if formatting of values also required in SheetB.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for reply!
I tried that, but not working.

Let me explain. I have google sheet for collecting data from who visit our office. so In "visitors" Sheet there is Column "D2:D" is for contact numbers. and another sheet "Application" who already registered with us. there is contact number column is "G3:G" . Now! some people who already registered with us can visit our office again. So, I just want to know yes, they already visited and their data already in our registered application list. or vise versa. from application to visitors.